# I want a job to be run on first 1-8 days of a month at different times in each day in CA Autosys

Tags: autosys

I want a job to be run on first 1-8 days of a month at different times in each day in CA Autosys.

Example:

Job A should run as per below example

DAY 1 & DAY 2 & DAY 3 & DAY 5:  3am, 7am, 11am, 8:30pm 
DAY 4 & DAY 6 : 3am, 7am, 11am

Please help me with the above condition.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by creating two jobs with two different calenders.

First create Job A with calendar A:

Select the dates day1, day2, day3, day5 in calendar A and provide the timings .

Similarly create Job A1 with calendar A1 in calendar A1 and provide the timings .

Select the dates day4, day6.

Please find the below example jil:

insert_job: JobA

job_type: cmd or box

run_calendar: Calendar_A

start_times: "03:00, 07:00, 11:00, 20:30"

Similarly, for the second job:

insert_job: JobA1

job_type: cmd or box

run_calendar: Calendar_A1

start_times: "03:00, 07:00, 11:00"

Comment: But that means duplicating the job.